# Proofs in coq using MSet

Tags: set, coq

So I am still new to coq and MSets are giving me some issues. Here are two functions to compute whether an element is in a list or set, please let me know if you think the set_contains definition is correct or if there is a better way to do it.  Thanks for any help.

```
    Require Import MSets ZArith.
    Module mset := MSetAVL.Make Positive_as_OT.
    Notation pos_set := mset.t.

    Definition set_contains (x : positive) (s : pos_set) :=
      mset.mem x s.

    Fixpoint list_contains (x : positive) (l : list positive) : bool :=
      match l with
      | nil => false
      | y :: l' =>
        if Pos.eqb x y then true
        else nodelist_contains x l'
     end.

   Lemma nodelist_nodeset_contains :
      forall x  (s : pos_set),
        (nodelist_contains x (mset.elements s)) = (nodeset_contains x s).
    Proof.
      induction s.
      destruct list_contains.
      destruct set_contains.
      auto.
```

It seems that set_contains evaluates to true at the base case after the destructs and i'm not sure why. Would the set not be mset.empty during that stage of the proof?

I also do not know how to work with the mset.In, I have trouble with the base case of this proof, obviously I have the same problem. I want to eventually state:

```
    Lemma nodelist_containsP :
      forall x (l : pos_set),
        reflect (mset.In x l) (nodeset_contains x l).
```

In case anyone is interested here is how I did this proof.

```
       intros.
       apply iff_reflect.
       unfold nodeset_contains.
       symmetry.
       apply mset.mem_spec.
       Qed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list_contains` and `set_contains` are functions so it does not make sense to try to `destruct` them. Coq tries to infer what you meant and guesses that you want to case on the value of an expression starting with `list_contains` and `set_contains` respectively.

This is not what you want. What you want is to observe the behaviour of the two functions on the same input. And you can do so by inspecting it.

This should send you in the right direction:

```
  destruct s as [mset mset_isok].
  induction mset.
  + unfold set_contains, mset.mem.
    simpl.
    reflexivity.
  + unfold list_contains, set_contains, mset.mem.
    simpl.
```